# Ask user about rewriting file while moving file on Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am moving files by 
1) Copying initial file to a folder
2) Deleting an initial file in the end.
If the file with the same name already exists in destination folder, I create an alertdialog "Rewrite this file?". But when the Message appears, the initial file is being deleted.

I start copying and deleteing methods in the same new Thread(...) and show alertdialog in UIthread.

```
//First class:
final File file = new File(initFilePath);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).copyFile(file,FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).getCurPath());
    FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).removeFile(file);
    updateUI();
}
}).start();

//FileFoldersLab:
public void copyFile(final File src, final String destPath){
final File f = new File(destPath+File.separator+src.getName());
if(f.exists()){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("The file already exists");
        builder.setMessage("Would you like to rewrite " + f.getPath()+ " ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Copying file
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
    //Showing the alert dialog
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        //Copying file
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful then please vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put remove files, inside rewrite confirmation and inside same file not found condition

**Change this**

```
   //First class:
final File file = new File(initFilePath);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).copyFile(file,FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).getCurPath());
    FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).removeFile(file);
    updateUI();
}
}).start();

//FileFoldersLab:
public void copyFile(final File src, final String destPath){
final File f = new File(destPath+File.separator+src.getName());
if(f.exists()){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("The file already exists");
        builder.setMessage("Would you like to rewrite " + f.getPath()+ " ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Copying file
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
    //Showing the alert dialog
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        //Copying file
    }
}
```

**Into this**

```
        //First class:
        final File file = new File(initFilePath);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).copyFile(file,FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).getCurPath());

            updateUI();
        }
        }).start();

        //FileFoldersLab:
        public void copyFile(final File src, final String destPath){
        final File f = new File(destPath+File.separator+src.getName());
        if(f.exists()){
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setTitle("The file already exists");
                builder.setMessage("Would you like to rewrite " + f.getPath()+ " ?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Copying file

     //After copying 
FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
            //Showing the alert dialog
                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                //Copying file
    //After copying
    FileFoldersLab.get(getContext()).removeFile(file);
            }
        }
```